# Can someone help me with this syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdin

This maybe silly but I'm unfamiliar with the syntax here:

```
var stdin = '';
process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
  stdin += chunk;
}).on('end', function() {
  var lines = stdin.split('\n');
  for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    process.stdout.write(lines[i]);
  }
});
```

I'm supposed to write a program that squares a number, which I know how to do, but I've never encountered this type of structure. I understand the loop and that `process.stdout.write` is essentially `console.log` The test cases inputs are 5 and 25. Outputs should be 25 and 625.

Where am I supposed to write the code to do this?

Comment: You have two unrelated questions. One about how to write a program that squares a number, and what the syntax/structure is...

Comment: You can start here : https://nodejs.org/api/

Comment: @y-intercept I've just come across this exact question, could you tell me where you placed your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put it in a file `sample.js` and run it:

```
node sample.js
```

This `process.stdin` refers to the stdin stream (incoming data from other applications, for example, a shell input , so basically this:

```
process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
  stdin += chunk;
})
```

says, whenever there new `data` (user typed in something into a console, hosting application send some data), read it and store it in `stdin` variable. Then, when the `stdin` stream is over (for example, a user finished entering data):

```
.on('end', function() {
  var lines = stdin.split('\n');
  for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    process.stdout.write(lines[i]);
  }
})
```

the code outputs back what a user typed in.

Comment: @y-intercept  If you see any answers you like, feel free to upvote them. If one of the answers best solves your problem, feel free to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Ouroborus, he can't upvote yet, he needs 1 more point, I upvoted this question, you can upvote it too :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears all of the infrastructure is there. All that's left is actually squaring your numbers.

`process.stdin` and `process.stdout` are [node streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) which are asynchronous and so use events to tell you what's going on with them. `data` is the event for when there is data ready to process and `end` is for when there's no more data. The code just snarfs `process.stdin` and then, once the data is all in memory, processes it.

The `end` anonymous function would probably be best implemented like this:

```
function() {
  stdin.split('\n').foreach(function(line){
     var value = line.trim()|0;
     process.stdout.write(value * value);
  });
}
```

Off topic: The memory footprint might be improved by processing the stream as it comes in rather than collecting it and then processing it all at once. This depends on the sizes of the input and the input buffer:

```
var buffer = '';
var outputSquare = function(line) {
  var value = line.trim()|0;
  process.stdout.write(value * value);
};
process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
  var lines = (buffer + chunk).split('\n');
  buffer = lines.pop();
  lines.foreach(outputSquare);
}).on('end', function() {
  outputSquare(buffer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

const squareNum = (num) => (num ** 2);

let stdin = '';
process.stdin.on('data', (chunk) => {
  stdin = `${stdin}${chunk}`;
  console.log(squareNum(parseInt(chunk)));
}).on('end', () => {
  //const lines = stdin.trim().split('\n');
  //for (const line of lines) {
   // process.stdout.write(`${line}\n`);
  //}
});
```